# Target script tags within element and remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, code-injection

Now I was thinking of turning my blog into a user generated blog where people can post their own stuff. 
The problem with this is that it makes my blog vulnerable to jquery injections. I searched and found people talking about whitelists and using server side scripts but since my blog is hosted by Tumblr where I'm limited to CSS, HTML and jQuery I'm not sure if that's a solution.

Now this is the only part other users can change/target:

```
<h2><a href="Link" class="Title">
    <p>//THIS IS WHERE THE USER GENERATED CONTENT GOES</p>
</a></h2>
```

And an example of the problem would be if they decided to do this:

```
<h2><a href="Link" class="Title">
        <p><script>alert('injected');<script></p>
</a></h2>
```

Now, is there anyway to prevent the script above from going off? Since I'm limited to jQuery I was thinking of a solution like:

```
       var ContentWithScript = Anything inside <p></p> tags (or any other way to target it)
       $(ContentWithScript).find('script').remove();
```

Or

```
$(.Title).getElementsByTagName('p')
     var Content=(this)
     if Content contains string ('script) {
           remove }
```

Comment: Have you tried a test injection using your injected sample code above?

Comment: This is a bad idea. You don't need `<script>` tags to execute JavaScript.

Comment: Actually, you need. otherwise, it'll just display as plain text.

Comment: Yes and it worked. Tumblr (the blog I'm using) has a markup provided. However users can manually turn it off and start messing with the HTML.

Comment: @KyleEmmanuel: Not in IE7 and below: `<div style="width: expression(alert('foo'));"></div>`

Comment: @Blender: Who the heck uses IE7 and below? hehehe. you do have a point anyway.

Comment: you can use the iframe sandbox and content attributes in newer browsers, but that leaves a lot of folks left to dry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be blocking this client side.

If you are using jQuery you are most likely running your script in an on ready function, something that looks like this

```
$(function(){ /* some code */ });
```

Because of this, the evil script will already be running.

User server side sanitising to strip out all harmful script tags that people are able to post. You can also use wysiwyg editors, but you should still clean the data server side after.

It's the only way to be sure.

Comment: Thanks but like I said I do not have access to server side script. Anyway I came up with a work around by using Tumblr's markdown. It's not pretty but it'll have to do if there's no other solution.